# Android admob fatal exception

Tags: java, android, exception

I am trying to ad admob ads to my app but I am getting this error in the logcat when it launches. The app ran fine before I added the admob so I think it's something to do with that.

```
03-16 19:08:00.683: E/AndroidRuntime(529): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.musicbynumbers.scalesads/com.musicbynumbers.scalesads.MainMenu}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-16 19:08:00.683: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
03-16 19:08:00.683: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-16 19:08:00.683: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-16 19:08:00.683: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-16 19:08:00.683: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-16 19:08:00.683: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-16 19:08:00.683: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-16 19:08:00.683: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 19:08:00.683: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-16 19:08:00.683: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-16 19:08:00.683: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-16 19:08:00.683: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-16 19:08:00.683: E/AndroidRuntime(529): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-16 19:08:00.683: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at com.musicbynumbers.scalesads.MainMenu.onCreate(MainMenu.java:69)
03-16 19:08:00.683: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-16 19:08:00.683: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
03-16 19:08:00.683: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  ... 11 more
```

Java of MainMenu:

```
   package com.musicbynumbers.scales;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.musicbynumbers.pianoscalesadscopy.R;






public class MainMenu extends  LicenseCheckActivity implements View.OnClickListener   {

    Button majScales, minHarm, minMel, majArp, minArp, chrome, cont, pent,how;
    ImageButton mainMenu;
    Intent j;
    Intent k;
    Intent l;
    Intent m;
    Intent n;
    Intent o;
    Intent p;
    Intent q;
    Intent r;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DITHER);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
          Toast.makeText(this, "Checking Application License", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          // Check the license
          //checkLicense();
         j = new Intent(MainMenu.this, majorScales.class);
         k = new Intent(MainMenu.this, minorHarmonic.class);
         l = new Intent(MainMenu.this, MajorArpeggios.class);
         m = new Intent(MainMenu.this, MinorArpeggios.class);
         n = new Intent(MainMenu.this, ChromaticScales.class);
         o = new Intent(MainMenu.this, ContraryMotion.class);
         p = new Intent(MainMenu.this, PentatonicScales.class);
         q = new Intent(MainMenu.this, minorMelodic.class);
         r = new Intent(MainMenu.this, HowItWorks.class);

        mainMenu = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagelogo);
        majScales = (Button) findViewById(R.id.majorscalesb);
        minHarm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minorharmonicb);
        minMel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minormelodicb);
        majArp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.majorarpeggiosb);
        minArp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minorarpeggiosb);
        chrome = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chromaticscalesb);
        cont = (Button) findViewById(R.id.contraryb);
        pent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pentatonicscaleb);
        how = (Button) findViewById(R.id.howitworksb);
        majScales.setOnClickListener(this);
        mainMenu.setOnClickListener(this);
        minHarm.setOnClickListener(this);
        minMel.setOnClickListener(this);
        majArp.setOnClickListener(this);
        minArp.setOnClickListener(this);
        chrome.setOnClickListener(this);
        cont.setOnClickListener(this);
        pent.setOnClickListener(this);
        how.setOnClickListener(this);



    }









        @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch(arg0.getId()){
                case R.id.imagelogo:
                    Intent i =  new Intent(MainMenu.this, MainMenu.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;
                case R.id.majorscalesb:

                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.minorharmonicb:

                    startActivity(k);
                    break;
                case R.id.majorarpeggiosb:

                    startActivity(l);
                    break;
                case R.id.minorarpeggiosb:

                    startActivity(m);
                    break;
                case R.id.chromaticscalesb:

                    startActivity(n);
                    break;
                case R.id.contraryb:

                    startActivity(o);
                    break;
                case R.id.pentatonicscaleb:

                    startActivity(p);
                    break;
                case R.id.minormelodicb:

                    startActivity(q);
                    break;

                case R.id.howitworksb:

                    startActivity(r);
                    break;


    }

}
}
```

activity_main_menu xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/musicbynumbersbg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100"
    tools:context=".MainMenu" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imagelogo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="90"
        android:background="@drawable/topbanner"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="10" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="100" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/howitworksb"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="How to Use the App" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/majorscalesb"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Major Scales" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/minormelodicb"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Minor Melodic Scales" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/minorharmonicb"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Minor Harmonic Scales" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/majorarpeggiosb"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Major Arpeggios" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/minorarpeggiosb"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Minor Arpeggios" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/chromaticscalesb"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Chromatic Scales" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/contraryb"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Contrary Motion" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/pentatonicscaleb"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Pentatonic Scale" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId=" a15144ab55b99a9"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance for trying to help.

Comment: What is at MainMenu.java:69?

Comment: mainMenu.setOnClickListener(this); eclipse dosen't show any errors.

Comment: @user1854482 **`RuntimeExceptions`** occur when your code compiles but doesn't run properly. The code compiled so Eclipse didn't throw any warning.

Comment: thanks i never knew  that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are not setting right layout here.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);  <<You set the menu layout.
```

You must set the layout which is in res folder.

If you have layout.xml in res folder then set it like

```
setContentView(R.layout.layout);
```

Edit: Clean the project and run it.

Comment: i added the xml for activity_main_menu so you can see any problems its definitely in the res folder

Comment: @user1854482 Yes i have seen clean the project then run it.